# How can i send fax using python when i have my own fax machine?

Tags: python, fax

i have been trying to make a fax list and send them rapidly by python .
all packages like phaxio , interfax,.. are sending fax through their own server but i have Panasonic fax and want to send fax by it.
is there other packages to send fax using windows fax and scan?
how can i send fax using my own fax machine?

Answer (score 1):

If your fax machine is compatible with the Windows Fax and Scan application and is linked to your computer through a USB or serial port, you may use the pywin32 package to automate sending faxes through the Windows Fax and Scan program.

```py
import win32com.client

fax = win32com.client.Dispatch("FaxComEx.FaxDocument")
fax.Body = "Hello World!"
fax.Recipients.Add("1234567890")
fax.Subject = "Test Fax"
fax.FaxNumber = "1234567890"
fax.Send()
```

```py
import win32api

win32api.ShellExecute(0, "faxsend", " /d 1234567890 testfax.txt", "", 0)
```

This will send the file testfax.txt as a fax to the number 1234567890.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Please don't do this: you're posting an answer, with code, to a question that is nothing but a requirement. Also this question is almost 2 years old - absolutely no reason to post an answer to this (and this is not the first time you've now done this to off-topic questions)

Comment: sorry I didn't know, I thought I was just supposed to answer the questions, thought it was an interesting question. Same with the last one.